# i want to code this react function to get data from thirdweb and display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, thirdweb

Help me to get fetch information from blockchain and display in the browser. i want know how to call this thirdweb functions in react.
Below code is a solidity code used to create a user in our system.

```
function createUser(string memory _userId, string memory _fName, string memory _lName, string memory _mobile, string memory _dob, uint256 _age, string memory _nationality, string memory _gender) public {
        if(!chkexisitinguserId(_userId)){
            users[_userId] = User(_fName, _lName, _mobile, _dob, _age,_nationality,_gender);
            noofUser++;
            allUserId[k] = _userId;
            k++;
        }
    }

function getUser(string memory _userId) public view returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, uint256, string memory, string memory) {
        User memory user = users[_userId];
        return (user.fName, user.lName, user.mobile, user.dob, user.age, user.nationality, user.gender);
    }
```

The below code is thirdweb libary code to interact with smart contract. The below code is stored in refer.js file.

```
import { useContract, useContractWrite } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";

export default function Component() {
  const { contract } = useContract("0xBB417720eBc8b76AdeAe2FF4670bbc650C3E791f");
  const { mutateAsync: createUser, isLoading } = useContractWrite(contract, "createUser")

  const call = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await createUser([ "John0312", "John", "s", "8090890367", "03-11-2000", 20, "India", "M" ]);
      console.info("contract call successs", data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("contract call failure", err);
    }
    
  }
}

export default function Component() {
  const { contract } = useContract("0xBB417720eBc8b76AdeAe2FF4670bbc650C3E791f");
  const { data, isLoading } = useContractRead(contract, "getUser", _userId)
}
```

The smart contract is deployed in thirdweb and trying to access it. I am stuck at how to call this "call" async function from app.js.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
function App(){
const handleclick = async (e) => {
    await call();
  }
 return (
<button onClick={handleclick}>click me</button>
  )
}

export default App
```

it generates error like undefined function call().

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new hook (`useCall.js`) who's job is simply to instantiate the `useContract` and `useContractWrite` hooks, then define the `call()` method for you to use in any component.

In this example, call() is the only thing returned from the hook. It's wrapped inside `useCallback` to ensure it's only defined when `createUser` is defined.

```
export default function useCall() {
  const { contract } = useContract("0xBB417720eBc8b76AdeAe2FF4670bbc650C3E791f");
  const { mutateAsync: createUser, isLoading } = useContractWrite(contract, "createUser")

  const call = React.useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const data = await createUser([ "John0312", "John", "s", "8090890367", "03-11-2000", 20, "India", "M" ]);
      console.info("contract call successs", data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("contract call failure", err);
    }
  }, [createUser]);
  
  return call;
}
```

Now inside of any component you can use the hook and get the `call()` function:

```
import useCall from './useCall';

export default function Component() {
  const call = useCall();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await call();
    })();
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass second argument of

```
const { contract } = useContract("0xBB417720eBc8b76AdeAe2FF4670bbc650C3E791f");
```

as contract json

```
const { contract } = useContract("0xBB417720eBc8b76AdeAe2FF4670bbc650C3E791f",CONTRAT_API);
```